# Jasper Hiding Page Break on Specific Pages

Tags: jasper-reports, ireport

Hi I want a page break that goes after each group except for the last group. Currently my page breaks separates all the groups nicely, but I would like the last group to be connected to the last page. The page break separates my last page footer, leaving a huge amount of space on the last page. Is there any way to do this?

I'm thinking of hiding the last page break but I'm unsure of how to do it.
Attempts to do a put into $P{REPORT_PARAMATERS_MAP} within the print when expression band of the summary band have been unsuccessful.

I tried placing the following into the 'print when expression' band of the summary band:

```
new Boolean($P{REPORT_PARAMETERS_MAP}.put("LastPageNumber",new Integer($V{PAGE_NUMBER}.intValue()-1)).equals("dummyPrintWhen"))
```

And using this on 'print when expression' of the break:

```
new Boolean(!$V{PAGE_NUMBER}.equals($P{REPORT_PARAMETERS_MAP}.get("LastPageNumber")))
```

But it's not working the way I want. It still gives me the last page footer all by itself on another page while still leaving a large amount of space on the previous page.

By taking out `"!"` on the break's 'print when expression', the breaks don't happen and I get my last page footer on a page all by itself as there is no more space on the previous page.

----------------------------EDIT--------------------------------

Printing `$P{REPORT_PARAMETERS_MAP}.get("LastPageNumber")` for every page
gives me `null`.

----------------------------EDIT--------------------------------

What am I doing wrong?

I'm currently using iReport 3.0.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what I'm trying to do might not be possible simply because the last page number can only be compiled at the end of the report, while the page breaks happen as the report is compiled.

I think this can be confirmed by nobody answering the question on this page: http://www.coderanch.com/t/579950/open-source/Jasper-report-store-total-number

Answer (score 0):

What if you use ?

```
new Boolean(new Boolean($V{PAGE_NUMBER}.equals($P{REPORT_PARAMETERS_MAP}.get("LastPageNumber")))==false)
```

Comment: still nothing. Thanks though! but i felt the dual Booleans were a bit redundant. and the code didnt really work so I changed it to `$V{PAGE_NUMBER}.equals($P{REPORT_PARAMETERS_MAP}.get("LastPageNumber"))?Boolean.FALSE:Boolean.TRUE`

Comment: wait scratch my earlier comment, but the code you provided still doesn't work.....I used `new Boolean(new Boolean($V{PAGE_NUMBER}.equals($P{REPORT_PARAMETERS_MAP}.get("LastPageNumber")))==Boolean.TRUE)` and `new Boolean(new Boolean($V{PAGE_NUMBER}.equals($P{REPORT_PARAMETERS_MAP}.get("LastPageNumber")))==Boolean.FALSE)` but there was no page break for both..Thanks though!